# Stop a VSTS automated build from getting the entire team project

Tags: tfs, build-automation, azure-pipelines

How can I stop a VSTS automated build from getting the entire team project?  I have our entire company all in one giant team project and a huge portion of the build time is taken by getting the unnecessary files.  I need a way to tell the build to only get files from a specific path.  I'm guessing that it's either an MSBuild argument or not possible but if I knew I wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify mappings in Repository of your build definition.

[image]

Make sure that you **Map** all folders that contain files that your build process requires. For example, if you add another project, you might have to add another mapping to the workspace.

**Cloak** folders you don't need. By default the root folder of team project is mapped in the workspace. This configuration results in the build agent downloading all the files in the version control folder of your team project. If this folder contains lots of data, your build could waste build system resources and slow down your build process by downloading large amounts of data that it does not require.